# Javascript: on click change button text color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey I have the below javascript code with accompanying HTML.  I am trying to get each button when clicked to change the text color to blue and then when the next button is clicked it changes text of the previously clicked button back to green. basically only the most recently clicked button has blue text.  I have tried this code but with this it changes all button text to blue on the first button click.  Any help is appreciated.  Javascript, HTML, and CSS below.

```
function swapIphoneImage( tmpIPhoneImage ) {
    var el = document.getElementById('my-link');
    var el1 = document.getElementById('my-link1');
    var el2 = document.getElementById('my-link2');
    var el3 = document.getElementById('my-link3');
    var el4 = document.getElementById('my-link4');

    var iphoneImage = document.getElementById('iphoneImage');
    iphoneImage.src = tmpIPhoneImage;
    el.className = 'clicked-class';
    el1.className = 'clicked-class1';
    el2.className = 'clicked-class2';
    el3.className = 'clicked-class3';
    el4.className = 'clicked-class4';

}
```

html

```
<ul class="features">
    <li><a id="my-link"  href="javascript:swapIphoneImage('wscalendarws.png');" title="">HaPPPs Calendar</a></li>
    <li><a id="my-link1"  href="javascript:swapIphoneImage('wsweekendws.png');" title="">Weekend Events</a></li>
    <li><a id="my-link2"  href="javascript:swapIphoneImage('wsfollowingws.png');" title="">Places & People</a></li>
    <li><a id="my-link3"  href="javascript:swapIphoneImage('wstemplateviewws.png');" title="">Customize Events</a></li>
    <li><a id="my-link4"  href="javascript:swapIphoneImage('wscheckinws.png');" title="">Interaction</a></li>
</ul>
```

> css

```
a#my-link.clicked-class {
    color: #71a1ff !important;
}
a#my-link1.clicked-class1 {
    color: #71a1ff !important;
}
a#my-link2.clicked-class2 {
    color: #71a1ff !important;
}
a#my-link3.clicked-class3 {
    color: #71a1ff !important;
}
a#my-link4.clicked-class4 {
    color: #71a1ff !important;
}
```

> Where am I failing?

Comment: why do you have 5 different classes, when you only appear to have a need for two: "clicked" and "not clicked". It makes life harder for yourself...

Comment: yeah i figured i was making things hard on myself, but I tried it with two classes and same results.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151161/how-to-set-the-last-clicked-anchor-to-be-a-different-color-from-all-other-links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using JavaScript to change the classes then you only need one class to determine which one is clicked.

Here is an example:

JS:

```
   $("UL.features LI A").click(function(){
      $("UL.features LI A").removeClass('clicked');
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
   });
```

CSS:

```
A.clicked {
    color:#71a1ff !important;
}
```

Here it is in jsfiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/57PBm/

**EDIT:** This solution uses JQuery which will I would definitely suggest using if you are not already

Comment: where would I add the javascript in my file?  I try addding it above my other javascript function in the head and no dice, tried below and nothing.

Comment: NEvermind, I got it.  thanks Ryan, this was the perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite JS code to:

```
function swapIphoneImage( elThis, tmpIPhoneImage ) {
    var el = document.getElementByClassName('clicked-class');

    var iphoneImage = document.getElementById('iphoneImage');
    iphoneImage.src = tmpIPhoneImage;

    el.className = '';
    elThis.className = 'clicked-class';
}
```

and each button to:

```
<li><a id="my-link" href="javascript:swapIphoneImage(this, 'wscalendarws.png');" title="">HaPPPs Calendar</a></li>
```

You don't need to set up 5 CSS classes for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing every element to a clicked class. Just pass in a number to the function that identifies which button to color blue, then color that one blue and all the others green via JS.