# Can I style the last <a name> that was clicked on?

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a unordered list which jump to sections of the page. What I want to do is when the user clicks or scrolls down to a particular section where there is a 'a name', the `<a href>` becomes highlighted via css. Is this possible? Code below which will hopefully make more sense...

```css
#left-nav {
  width: 14rem;
  float: left;
}
#left-nav ul li {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #5c5c5c;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 14px 0 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 167px;
  list-style: none;
}
.page-content {
  width: 54rem;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#title1">title1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#title2">title2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#title3">title3</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>

<a name="title1"></a>
<a name="title2"></a>
<a name="title3"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure css doesn't work, no.

You could do something like that:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXJxea

```
<div id="left-nav">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="highlightLi(this)"><a href="#title1">title1</a>
    </li>
    <li onclick="highlightLi(this)"><a href="#title2">title2</a>
    </li>
    <li onclick="highlightLi(this)"><a href="#title3">title3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#left-nav ul li[data-highlight="true"] {background-color: #550055;}
```

js:

```
function highlightLi(e) {
  var i=0;
  var parent_element = e.parentElement;
  while(parent_element.children[i]) {
    if (parent_element.children[i].tagName = "LI")
      parent_element.children[i].removeAttribute("data-highlight");
    i++;
  }
  e.setAttribute("data-highlight", "true");
}
```

I just have a function that sets an attribute to the clicked element, which has additional css-code.
Before setting the attribute, we have to remove it from all siblings, otherwise they wouldn't clear, so we loop through the children of the parent element (<ul>). With some extra security because firefox has none <li> children in there.

Answer (score 0):

To highlight the visited link, you need to use the `:visited` selector. Note that there is a bug where you need to assign a background first to your `a` element for the `background-color` to work on a `a:visited` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/fsxyeetd/

```
a:visited { background-color: rgb(255,0,255); }
a{background-color:white;}
```

Instead of `white` you can use inherit if your website has another background color. For the scrolling, you will need Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think WackyRacer8 wants to highlight only the last clicked link. Loli's example shows how to highlight all :visited links.

Here's a similar question, with answer. Maybe it can help you out:
[How to set the last-clicked anchor to be a different color from all other links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151161/how-to-set-the-last-clicked-anchor-to-be-a-different-color-from-all-other-links)

Comment: OP asked for a CSS-only solution though